# Ascii-art tag question marked as off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

I saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1719349/connecting-the-slashes-in-asciiflow) question, which piqued my interest as I'd not seen the tag used before. It was closed as off-topic, which leads to my question; what would be an on-topic [ascii-art](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) question? If there aren't any, then why is the tag still available for selection?

Answer (score 4):

Its a webapp - and as such out of scope

Answer (score 0):

> what would be an on-topic [ascii-art](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) question

The [ascii-art](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) tag (just click on it - It's really a link) shows a number of questions that weren't closed as off-topic (although a few probably should have been).  My first thought (and one that is represented) would be questions around [figlet](http://www.figlet.org), which is locally installed software (on-topic) to create text-based ASCII art, of sorts.

Really, any *locally installed* software to create ASCII art would likely be on-topic (as long as it met all other criteria).  It's just, as @JourneymanGeek said in the other answer, that the particular post you mentioned was about a WebApp, which is off-topic.